# How to inject a runtime value into headers of Next.js app response?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

We are using next.js v13 with pages/ folder.

I need to inject value into the headers that is *only* known at the runtime.

How do we do it?

I found documentation talking about [serverRuntimeConfig](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration), but that does not work in v13.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext,
) => {
  context.res.setHeader(
    'x-contra-release-version',
    process.env.SENTRY_RELEASE ?? 'release',
  );

  // ...
}
```

Note that `getConfig` does not work in this case.